# trouble getting simple jquery slider to work

Tags: jquery

What i am tring to code is that, when my slides class with filter first should animate to the left and fadeout and then it should get appended to the bottom of the carousel inner class. somehow.. its not working. please help. Thanks in advance

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/slider.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="carousel_inner">
            <figure class="slides">
                <img src="assets/images/post4.jpg">
            </figure>
            <figure class="slides">
                <img src="assets/images/post4-2.jpg">
            </figure>
            <figure class="slides">
                <img src="assets/images/post4-3.jpg">
            </figure>
        </div>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slider.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
       $(".slides:first").animate({"margin-left":"-290px"}).fadeOut().end().appendTo(".carousel_inner");
    },2000);
});
```

Comment: what are the css for the slider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would move the appendTo code to finish callback for the animation, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
      var firstSlide = $(".slides:first")[0];
       $(firstSlide).animate({"margin-left":"-290px", "opacity": 0.5}, 
                             1600, //length of the slide/fadeout animation
                             function() {
                               //animation is complete, so move the slide to the end and fade it back it in, also reset the margin back to 0
                                $(firstSlide).appendTo('.carousel_inner').css("margin-left", 0).fadeTo(1000, 1);
                              }
       );
    },3000);
});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/nobrien/pen/redYPQ

Answer (score 0):

Your slide is not appending because `.end()` will drop last selector and returns to previous selector in chaining. So `$('.slides:first').end()` will result in not existing element.

Comment: so should i append the selector directly without using end? pls help

Answer (score 0):

```
setInterval(function(){
    var $first = $(".slides:first");
   $first.animate({"margin-left":"-290px"}, function() {
        var $img = $("<img />").attr("src", $first.find("img").attr("src")).on("load", function() {
            var fig = $("<figure />").addClass("slides");
            fig.append($(this));

            $first.parent().append(fig);
            $first.remove();
        });
   });
}, 2000);
```

fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/36nzoxvk/1/

Comment: its slides to the left, then i need to append it to the back and do it in a continous loop.. your code is not looping

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you inspect the .carousel-inner div, you will see that the elements are looping.  The reason you don't see it is because the image is not found.  But if the images were there, it would loop.

Comment: i tried it with images. and yaa in the console the images are appending but its still not being displayed as the margin -left is not correct i think and the images are stuck at the left corner

Comment: Updated with new fiddle and added images for you.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to use is `.end().first()` instead of `.end()`, because `end()` traverses to the parent element then you need to select again.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".slides:first").animate({
      "margin-left": "-290px"
    })
      .fadeOut().end().first().removeAttr('style')
      .appendTo(".carousel_inner");
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel_inner">
    <figure class="slides">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/F00/fff">
    </figure>
    <figure class="slides">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/0F0/fff">
    </figure>
    <figure class="slides">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x200/00F/fff">
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is working.. but nor to the perfect.. i am still not getting the sliding to the left effect like in carousels (not that i am complaining). if u could fix that too.. it would be a great help

Comment: @VishnuprasadVenugopal Updated the answer.